# Converting a digital incremental encoder to an analogue voltage

Tags: analog, dac, encoder

Is there a way to convert the output of an incremental encoder (50% duty cycle) to an analogue voltage using analogue components? This is because the interface that I'm using doesn't handle a large enough sample rate to accurately determine the shaft angle with just using interrupts directly from the encoder. (Any other possible solutions are greatly appreciated)

P.S. using a potentiometer attached to the shaft is not a solution.

Comment: Quadrature encoder? No. there is not. Maybe you need a quad encoder counter IC

Comment: you cannot say that the encoder has 50% duty cycle output unless it is continuously spinning at a fixed rate

Answer (score 1):

so you have a bit stream with 2 bit flows (quadrature, right?)

use a binary up-down counter 74160/161 should be useful

be able to ZERO_SET the counter

then convert the counter's binary number to an analog voltage, using a digital-voltage convert (ADI should have some)

========================

You need to prepare a error analysis.

You have **THREE**  quantizers here.

Comment: I need at least 11 bits since one full rotation is around 1400 counts. So I assume I need a 12 bit dac

Comment: Ah no need! The shaft would only rotate 1/4 of a revolution so a 10 bit counter and dac is sufficient :D Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is **no** way to do this with analog[ue] components.

Easiest way is to use a microcontroller, scan the two quadrature inputs and store a digital voltage. You can then use a DAC (or the MCU PWM) to convert to an analog voltage. Most MCUs have some EEPROM so you could store the last position over a power interruption provided you take care to not write too often (for example, you could write the position after a delay of 30 seconds). That's because most EEPROMs may wear out after 100K to 1M write operations. There are also wear-leveling techniques. You could also consider a battery backup, which might be attractive if you need that for some other reason.

Comment: There probably is some cool, interesting and completely impractical way to do this with analog components :P

Comment: @BeB00  All absolute statements are wrong.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Therefore there must  be at least one that is right!

Answer (score 1):

Any solution that uses a simple counter for incremental encoding suffers a problem: glitching at counter transitions. So, for example, wiring up some '163s to an R-2R DAC will yield a noisy ramp signal.

For this reason, encoders that output absolute values (like what's being proposed here) use Gray code. With Gray code only one bit changes at a time. More about that here: https://www.quantumdev.com/understanding-gray-code-for-rotary-encoders/

You also need to detect the direction. There's some logic there, even specialized (and now obsolete, like the HCTL-2000) chips too.

If, however, the sensor was processed by something that masks the glitches and detects the direction, then outputs these to some kind of a DAC or PWM output...

And one other thing: index. Your actuator will need a sensor to establish a 'home' position. Again, if you just had something that could see that too, and reset the count...

All these things point to using a small microcontroller.

Or, buy it. https://www.genesisautomationonline.com/site/pdf/products/GAO/Motrona/UpdatedPDFs2017/Zu252_CountModule.pdf

Answer (score 0):

It will be a little convoluted, but possible, First start out with some circuitry to break out a step and direction signal, below is the direction, for the step from memory it is an XOR gate between the 2 signals (you will need to filter the encoder outputs to prevent multiple transitions from noisy switching)

[image]
[Image Source](https://blog.mbedded.ninja/electronics/components/encoders/)

From that you feed it in to a binary up/down counter e.g. SN74ALS867A to give you a binary output from those counts (with some other logic to prevent it overflowing if you desire it to behave that way),

Then finally run it into a parrellel dac, or use the output of the binary counter as a crude R2R dac.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want to do.

For a crude measure of speed, you could use a differentiator if only pure analog technology is allowed (or monostable if you're allowed a 555 or 74123) to generate a fixed pulse width from every positive going edge.

This is followed by a low pass filter to convert that pulse density into an analog voltage representing speed (or an integrator to get a crude indication of position).

Things get a bit more complicated (but still feasible) if you have to handle rotation in both directions; I'll let you imagine the details.

For practical purposes or any real accuracy, Spehro's answer is correct.